# Bootstrap Responsive charts and Graphs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I am using Twitter's bootstrap for one of my application and want to show graphs and charts. I tried using Google charts and I have placed in the div container. However these charts aren't responsive. I want to know is there any other frameworks for displaying charts which are responsive and works with bootstrap.

Even is it possible to display responsive charts as of now?

Comment: Raphael has a great library for charts. Here's an example http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984903/1883256

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Options which I tried:

1. [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) they are clickable, but probaly you will need to apply custom CSS ([example here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/dashboardWidget.html))
2. [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) produces pie charts and line charts without using Flash. but you cannot "click" them on mobile device

Comment: Highcharts look good to me I am using that one now thanks!!!!

Comment: need one to be mobile responsive, is flot any good?

Comment: I didn't try it for long time so I don't know

Comment: Now, in 2106, highcharts is clickable and otherwise is quite advanced. Thanks for the links