# Make Google Chart Gauge responsive

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, google-visualization

I would like to create a Google Gauge charts which should be web-responsive.
I heard about setting the width to '100%' should work out, but it actually doesn't make any changes.

Following you can see my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Happiness', 40],

        ]);

        var options = {
          width: '100%', height: '100%',
          redFrom: 0, redTo: 40,
          yellowFrom:40, yellowTo: 70,
          greenFrom: 70, greenTo: 100,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('test'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Please see my example .[Example Test](http://www.joelschmid.ch/hevs/HappinessBarometer/results.php)

Does anyone know how to make it web-responsive?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The charts will not resize automatically.  You must set up an event handler that calls `chart.draw(data, options);` on resize:

```
function drawChart () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Happiness', 40]
    ]);

    var options = {
        redFrom: 0,
        redTo: 40,
        yellowFrom:40,
        yellowTo: 70,
        greenFrom: 70,
        greenTo: 100,
        minorTicks: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('test'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    function resizeHandler () {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
    }
}
```

Setting `height` and `width` to 100% in the options won't do anything for you.  You will need to set those in CSS for your container div:

```
#test {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind a few things: setting height to 100% doesn't do anything unless the parent element has a specific height; also, the height and width of a Gauge are determined by the smaller of the dimensions.  So if you increase the size of the screen without specifying the height of the container `#test` (or it's parent container), the likely outcome is that the chart won't change size.

Comment: The problem were some settings in the .css file... After setting it to a '100%' everything worked out :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just just assign the width 100% in options and a responsive div tag with width="100%" or here goes [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/v3Q9r/9/) link where you can see the live demo.

//html here

```
 <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

//js here

```
 var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':'100%',
                  };
```

Comment: Setting the width to '100%' in the options does not work !! see [doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options) for this.