# Google Charts API: Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, google-visualization

I just added a chart from Google Charts API into a webapp I'm working on. Just for some context, my webapp is built on AngularJS with Bootstrap. The charts are inserted using the [angular-google-chart](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart) module.

How do I make the chart display responsive? What I'd like to do is to keep the chart full width, and based on that sized automatically with a proper height. I can't seem to get that working.

I have tried making `width: 100%; height: 500px;` but it displays whitespace on smaller widths.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Google Chart Gauge responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979535/make-google-chart-gauge-responsive)

Comment: @asgallant: Definitely not a duplicate. Please read the question and context before marking it as such. This is with regard to angular-google-chart, an AngularJS module.

Comment: The answer is the same, regardless of whether it is an angular module or not: you have to redraw the chart from a resize event handler.

Answer (score 5):

This thing works for me fine:

1. Add a wrapper (div) on the main chart div and add following css

   ```
   min-height:500px;height: 100%;width: 100%;margin:auto;background:#fff;text-align:center
   ```
2. Add the following CSS to the chart div:

   ```
   min-height:500px;height: 100%;width: 100%;margin:auto;background:#fff;text-align:center
   ```
3. Add a simple window resize function

   ```
   $(window).resize(function(){
       drawChart();
   });
   ```

Comment: Yes, I don't need drawChart() to achieve what you shown me in the demo. I am able to achieve what is in the demo. However, the demo produces lots of white space that is caused by the min-height field. http://i.imgur.com/NqllaW6.png

Comment: you can use media queries to adjust white space due to min-height on different resolutions