# Javascript variable sticks with the last value overriding the first ones

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a function to display a google chart. I want to display a chart for every year stored in the database.
The problem i have been stuck with for hours is that, for example, the variable

```
var year
```

always have the last year as value.

For example, if i want to show a chart for every year (2013 and 2014), it only shows the chart for the year 2014 ignoring the first one. If  i only get the 2013 year data, it shows the 2013 year data.

It seems that it overrides all the data and just keeps the last value.

My code is the following:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($anios as $anio) 
    {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        <?php

        $datos=$difusion_stats->notas_stats_anio($anio->Año);
        ?>
          var year=<?=$anio->Año?>; console.log('First, the year value is '+year);
          var data=<?=$datos?>;
          var id_chart = 'chart_'+<?=$anio->Año?>;

            function drawChart() {
                console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
                console.log('Php current year value is: '+<?=$anio->Año?>);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?=$datos?>);

            var options = {
                    title: 'Distribución de notas y entrevistas en el año '+<?=$anio->Año?>,
                    legend: 'Porcentaje de los distintos tipos de eventos',
                    pieSliceText: 'texto',
                    slices : {
                        0 : {offset: 0.1}
                    },
                    /*sliceVisibilityThreshold: .2,//Para contraer el resto y poner "otro"*/
                    pieHole: 0.4,
                    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
                    tooltip: {showColorCode: true},
                    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                    height: 400,
                    titleTextStyle: {
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    },
                    legendTextStyle: {
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    }          
                };                      

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(id_chart));

                chart.draw(data, options);
                /*Para hacerlo responsive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984903/1883256*/
                function resizeHandler () {
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
                }
                else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
                }  

            }/*Fin de la función drawChart()*/
    </script>
        <?php
    }/*Fin del foreach PHP*/
?>
```

And the resulting javascript code are, in this case, two codes for each year: 2013 and 2014:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                          var year=2013; console.log('First, the year value is '+year);
              var data=[['tipo','Cantidad'],['nota',14],['entrevista',3]];
              var id_chart = 'chart_'+2013;

                function drawChart() {
                    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
                    console.log('Php current year value is: '+2013);
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['tipo','Cantidad'],['nota',14],['entrevista',3]]);

                var options = {
                        title: 'Distribución de notas y entrevistas en el año '+2013,
                        legend: 'Porcentaje de los distintos tipos de eventos',
                        pieSliceText: 'texto',
                        slices : {
                            0 : {offset: 0.1}
                        },
                        /*sliceVisibilityThreshold: .2,//Para contraer el resto y poner "otro"*/
                        pieHole: 0.4,
                        backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
                        tooltip: {showColorCode: true},
                        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                        height: 400,
                        titleTextStyle: {
                            color: '#FFFFFF'
                        },
                        legendTextStyle: {
                            color: '#FFFFFF'
                        }          
                    };                      

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(id_chart));

                    chart.draw(data, options);
                    /*Para hacerlo responsive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984903/1883256*/
                    function resizeHandler () {
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    }
                    if (window.addEventListener) {
                        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
                    }
                    else if (window.attachEvent) {
                        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
                    }  

                }/*Fin de la función drawChart()*/
        </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                          var year=2014; console.log('First, the year value is '+year);
              var data=[['tipo','Cantidad'],['nota',43],['entrevista',12]];
              var id_chart = 'chart_'+2014;

                function drawChart() {
                    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
                    console.log('Php current year value is: '+2014);
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['tipo','Cantidad'],['nota',43],['entrevista',12]]);

                var options = {
                        title: 'Distribución de notas y entrevistas en el año '+2014,
                        legend: 'Porcentaje de los distintos tipos de eventos',
                        pieSliceText: 'texto',
                        slices : {
                            0 : {offset: 0.1}
                        },
                        /*sliceVisibilityThreshold: .2,//Para contraer el resto y poner "otro"*/
                        pieHole: 0.4,
                        backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
                        tooltip: {showColorCode: true},
                        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                        height: 400,
                        titleTextStyle: {
                            color: '#FFFFFF'
                        },
                        legendTextStyle: {
                            color: '#FFFFFF'
                        }          
                    };                      

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(id_chart));

                    chart.draw(data, options);
                    /*Para hacerlo responsive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984903/1883256*/
                    function resizeHandler () {
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    }
                    if (window.addEventListener) {
                        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
                    }
                    else if (window.attachEvent) {
                        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
                    }  

                }/*Fin de la función drawChart()*/
        </script>
```

But the chart for 2013 is never displayed. :/

In this case, i am getting two years: 2013 and 2014. However, in the console log messages i see it overrides the 2013 year by replacing to the last year, so the messages are:

```
First, the year value is 2013
stats:273 After calling the setOnLoadCallback() function, the year value is 2013
stats:274 we are about to call the drawChart() function ... YEAR: 2013
stats:280 First, the year value is 2014
stats:286 After calling the setOnLoadCallback() function, the year value is 2014
stats:287 we are about to call the drawChart() function ... YEAR: 2014
**stats:290 Inside the function. Current year value is: 2014**
stats:290 Inside the function. Current year value is: 2014
```

The value 2013 is overwritten by 2014, why is this happening?
How can i fix this?

Comment: I think your chart is drawn inside `id_chart` each time you call `document.getElementById(id_chart)`. So only last chart remains drawn.

Comment: You can try my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PHP but problem may be in this line `var id_chart = 'chart_'+<?=$anio->Año?>;`. So try `console.log(id_chart);`. If this prints different each time then it should draw two different chart depending upon whether that element is present in DOM or not.  Otherwise

Try changing

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(id_chart));
```

to

```
var span=document.createElement('span');
document.getElementById(id_chart).appendChild(span);
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(span);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have defined the function draw_chart twice.Instead you should define it once and call it twice with different parameters for the year 2013 and 2014.

Your second script tag which contains code for the chart on year 2014 overrides for 2013 therefore it is only displaying for 2014

Answer (score 1):

`var year` is written into global JS scope in both cases.  By the time the `drawChart` function is run, both `var year` commands have been run, and so the year 2014 is used.

It will help you to reduce your problem to a smaller set of code, and you will see what happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var year=2013; console.log('First, the year value is '+year);

function drawChart() {
    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
    console.log('Php current year value is: '+2013);
}
script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var year=2014; console.log('First, the year value is '+year);

function drawChart() {
    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
    console.log('Php current year value is: '+2014);
}/*Fin de la función drawChart()*/
</script>
```

1. It calls setOnLoadCallback for a function named `drawChart`, which does not exist yet (however, declarations in JavaScript are "hoisted", in other words, the later `function drawChart` is considered to exist at the top of the scope, so it works.)
2. Then it sets `year = 2013`.
3. Then it defines drawChart with a log statement saying the PHP year is 2013 (because this code becomes static JS code) and what the *current* value of the JS var `year` is.
4. Then it calls setOnLoadCallback for `drawChart` again.
5. Then it sets `year = 2014`.  This is technically improper JS because it uses `var` for a variable that already exists, but it does still change the value.
6. Then it defines drawChart with a log statement saying the PHP year is 2014 (static again).
7. When the "callback" set to `onLoadCallback` runs (both run *after* all of the definitions above, up to #6, have completed), it uses the intended value of `drawChart` (because it is evaluated when `setOnLoadCallback` runs).  But when *that* function is run, it uses the *latest* value of `year`.

To fix this, you need to make sure that each callback has a *permanent* reference to the year you want to run it with.

**Solution 1:**  Remove the "year" variable and embed (from PHP) the value directly into each "drawChart" function:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var id_chart = 'chart_'+<?=$anio->Año?>;
    var year=<?=$anio->Año?>; console.log('First, the year value is '+year);
    var data = <?= $difusion_stats->notas_stats_anio($anio->Año); ?>;
    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
    console.log('Php current year value is: '+<?=$anio->Año?>);
    // ...
}
```

This uses an "anonymous function" to make sure that **each function set as a callback is unique**.

It also makes sure that the JS var declarations are **inside the function scope** so they do not affect each other.

**Solution 2:** Create a single drawChart function and call it with parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    function getDrawChartFunction(year, data) {
        return function() {
            console.log('Inside the drawChart() function. Current year value is: '+year);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

            var options = {
                title: 'Distribución de notas y entrevistas en el año '+ year
                //, ...
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_'+year));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }; // End of return of *anonymous function closure*
    }

<?php 
    foreach ($anios as $anio) 
    {
        $datos=$difusion_stats->notas_stats_anio($anio->Año);
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(getDrawChartFunction(
               <?=$anio->Año?>,
               <?=$datos?>
            ));
        </script>
    <?
    }
?>
```

This solution also uses an anonymous function, but this time, it **returns a anonymous closure using the *different* parameters from each time it is called**.

See my answer on Programmers for help on "[What is a closure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/what-is-a-closure/40708)"

### Remember:

In either case, you need to make sure that the code that is run by the call to "google.setOnLoadCallback" is run *later* ("asynchronously", it is run after "load", of the library and/or page).

This means that you have changed the values by the time it is run.

To fix this kind of problem, you need to make sure the function that draws your chart somehow "remembers" the values you need when you set them.

You can do this by embedding the values directly into a unique function, or creating a JavaScript function that points to the correct value (which is what the closure does).