# Google charts dashboard loads only if I right click on inspect element

Tags: google-visualization

I want to show some dashboard charts ([like these ones](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)), for example one PieChart and one BarChart.

The issue I have found is that these charts aren't displayed **unless**, I right click on Inspect element. And viceversa, if I have the *inspect element* tools already open, the charts aren't display either **until** I close the *inspect elements* tools.

I am using bootstrap, slim framework and eloquent orm.

In the case of the pieChart, the sample data displayed is the following:

```
        [
            {
                Area: "Actores y Procesos Sociales",
                Cantidad: 49
            },
            {
                Area: "Población y Estudios Demográficos",
                Cantidad: 41
            },
            {
                Area: "Estudios Agrarios",
                Cantidad: 40
            },
            {
                Area: "Instituciones Políticas",
                Cantidad: 35
            },
            {
                Area: "Sociedad y Cultura",
                Cantidad: 30
            },
            {
                Area: "Estudios Urbanos y Regionales",
                Cantidad: 26
            },
            {
                Area: "Estudios de la Educación y la Ciencia",
                Cantidad: 23
            }
        ]
```

Here is the code for both the PieChart and the BarChart:

In the html:

```
<head>
   <link href="http://132.248.234.17/sica15/public/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome-4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/sbadmin2-sidebar-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                        <div id="projectresearcher">
                            <div id="numberRangeFilter_control_div"></div> <div id="numberRangeFilter_chart_div"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                        <div id="institucionesPporproyecto_div">
                            <div id="numberRangeFilter_control_div_2"></div> <div id="numberRangeFilter_chart_div_2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

In the script:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http:/assets/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','table','controls'],'language': 'es'});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(proyectosporarea);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(institucionesPporproyecto);


    function proyectosporarea() {/*PROYECTOS POR ÁREA*/

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var proyectosporarea = {{proyectosporarea|json_encode|raw}};
        var totalproyectos = 0;
        data.addColumn('string', 'Área');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');
        $.each(proyectosporarea, function(index, value){
            var Cantidad = parseInt(value.Cantidad);
            totalproyectos += Cantidad;
            data.addRow([value.Area,Cantidad]);
        });

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('projectarea'));//var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('projectarea'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'numberRangeFilter_control_div',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Cantidad'
            }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'PieChart',
            'containerId': 'numberRangeFilter_chart_div',
            'options': {
                title: 'Número de proyectos vigentes por área de investigación (total: '+totalproyectos+')',
                backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
                height: 500,
            }
        });

        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);


        function resizeHandler () {
            dashboard.draw(data);//chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
        }
    }/*Fin de drawChart() Proyectos por área*/

function institucionesPporproyecto() {/*INSTITUCIONES POR NÚMERO DE PROYECTOS*/
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var proyectosporarea = {{institucionesPporproyecto|json_encode|raw}};
        var total = 0;
        var totalInvestigadores = 0;
        data.addColumn('string', 'Institución');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
        //Sumando los totales para después calcular el porcentaje
        $.each(proyectosporarea, function(indice,valor){
            var Cantidad = parseInt(valor.Cantidad);
            var Total = parseInt(Cantidad);
            total += Total;
        });
        $.each(proyectosporarea, function(index, value){
            var Cantidad = parseInt(value.Cantidad);
            var Porcentaje = ((Cantidad/total)*100);
            if(Porcentaje % 1 != 0){
                Porcentaje = Porcentaje.toFixed(0)+'%';
            }else{
                Porcentaje = Porcentaje + '%';
            }
            totalInvestigadores=totalInvestigadores+1;
            data.addRow([value.Institucion,Cantidad,Porcentaje]);
        });

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0, 1]);
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('institucionesPporproyecto_t'));
        table.draw(view, {width: '100%', height: '100%'});

        var dashboard2 = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('institucionesPporproyecto_div'));/*Cambie chart por dashboard*/
        var control2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType':'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId':'numberRangeFilter_control_div_2',
            'options':{
                'filterColumnIndex':1,
                'minValue':0,
                //'maxValue':60,
            }
        });
        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType':'BarChart',
            'containerId':'numberRangeFilter_chart_div_2',
            'options':{
                title: 'Número de proyectos por institución participante (Total de Instituciones: '+totalInvestigadores+').',
                chartArea: {width: '45%'},
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Cantidad de proyectos',
                    minValue: 0
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Instituciones'
                },
                height: 1400,
                //width: 1200,
            }
        });

        dashboard2.draw(view);//chart.draw(view);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort',
                function(event) {
                    data.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
                    dashboard2.draw(view);//chart.draw(view);
                });

        //chart.draw(data, options); Aquí ando
        dashboard2.bind(control2,chart);
        function resizeHandler () {
            dashboard2.draw(data);//chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
        }
    }/*Fin de drawChart() Tabla Instituciones por número de proyectos*/

    </script>
```

Why is this happening? What should I fix so that those charts are displayed just after opening the URI in the browser?

**Solved**
The problem was in this part where there is this `function resizeHandler()`:

I had:

```
        dashboard2.bind(control2,chart);
        /*http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984903/1883256*/           
        function resizeHandler () { /*This helps make the chart responsive*/
            dashboard2.draw(data);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
        }
```

Instead of:

```
        dashboard2.bind(control2,chart);
        dashboard2.draw(data);
        /*http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984903/1883256*/
        function resizeHandler () {/*This helps make the chart responsive*/
            dashboard2.draw(data);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
        }
```

So, I had to repeat the call of the `dashboard.draw(data);` both inside the `function resizeHandler()` and outside it, below the `dashboard.bind()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, `setOnLoadCallback` should only be called once per page load
and you can include the `'callback'` in `google.charts.load`

try replacing this...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','table','controls'],'language': 'es'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(proyectosporarea);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(institucionesPporproyecto);
```

with this...

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'callback': function () {
        proyectosporarea();
        institucionesPporproyecto();
      },
      'packages': ['corechart','table','controls'],
      'language': 'es'
    });
```

next, each wrapper object needs a dom element
in function `proyectosporarea`, the objects appear to have the wrong `containerId`
see comments in the following snippet...

```
var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',  //<-- should = numberRangeFilter_control_div
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Cantidad'
    }
});

// Create a pie chart, passing some options
var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'PieChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div',  //<-- should = numberRangeFilter_chart_div
    'options': {
        title: 'Número de proyectos vigentes por área de investigación (total: '+totalproyectos+')',
        backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
        height: 500,
    }
});
```

Comment: hope this helps, if you still have problems, please share a sample of the data for each dashboard -- you can also check the browser's console for errors, usually by pressing F12

Comment: Thanks. I have made those changes you suggested, but I still have the same problem. The charts aren't displayed when I browse the URI. They're only displayed if I right click on _inspect element_.

Comment: Yeah, I have added more details on the surrounding HTML. I have tried following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vYMyz/9/) but I still get the same strange thing